# How to Merge all Text files in a Single file with Broken Lines?

Tags: batch-file, text, merge, copy, line-breaks

I'm using the codes below to combine all text files from a folder to a simple files, the problem is that the code does not break lines and ends up blending the words.

```
copy *.txt Combined.txt

Echo.
Echo Done!
Echo.

pause
```

**When it ends it, he stay like this:**

```
abcblue

123abcyellow

123abc
```

**When I expected it to go like this:**

```
ABC

blue

123

abc

yellow

123

abc
```

**Whats wrong?**

NOTE: I found this snippet of code on the internet and it looks like the subject:

```
FOR %f IN (*.txt) DO type %f >> Combined.txt & echo. >> Combined.txt
```

**In this context:**

```
type file1.txt >> newfile.txt
echo. >> newfile.txt
type file2.txt >> newfile.txt
echo. >> newfile.txt
type file3.txt >> newfile.txt
echo. >> newfile.txt
```

**But I need it to automatically grab all text files and combine.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the files are properly formed Windows (CRLF) ANSI text files then you could consider using `Type`?

```bat
Type *.txt>"..\Combined.txt"
```

This 'should' write to `Combined.txt` in the parent of the current directory. I have done this to prevent the command from trying to read it's own content, as it is also a `.txt` file. *Feel free to replace `"..\Combined.txt"` with a specific path if you prefer*.

If you would like the file names above each output `.txt` file then try changing the command to this:

```bat
Type *.txt>"..\Combined.txt" 2>&1
```

**Edit**

An additional option which also should prepend files with their names:

```bat
Find/V "" *.txt>"..\Combined.txt"
```

Comment: It is putting the name of the files below and jumping two lines, how to fix this?
Image: https://i.imgur.com/GeHYglT.png

Comment: As this basic command has no control over the existing content, It's not easily fixable without using more complicated coding and knowing more about the text files and their potential contents. But I have updated my answer with an additional option.

Comment: The new option combine better! But you're still putting the name of the files with extension, do not you have a way to simply delete those lines?

https://imgur.com/LbKYCCA.png

Comment: I refer you back to my last comment.

Comment: Okay, I'll open another question.