# How to remove all Strings containing this?

Tags: string, batch-file

I am using this code to combine all text files, however it is putting the name of the files with their extension in the final file, I would like to know how to clear this:

```
Find /v "" *.txt> "Combined.txt"
```

The file text:

```
---------- 001.TXT
abc

---------- 002.TXT
blue

123

---------- 003.TXT
abc

---------- 004.TXT
yellow

123

---------- 005.TXT
abc

---------- COMBINED.TXT
```

Comment: Theres already a similar question on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/111825/a-command-line-or-batch-cmd-to-concatenate-multiple-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```dos
Find/V "" *.txt|Find/V "---------- ">"Combined.txt"
```

…it should work fine unless you have a text file name containing ten contiguous dashes followed by a space, *(which is much less likely than not having a filename containing TXT)*.

*When I provided you with the `Find` option yesterday, I provided it as `an additional option which also should prepend files with their names`. Remember also that I explained that there were options too I you didn't want to include Combined.txt in the results.*

You can of course just change the extension then rename it thus:

```dos
Find/V "" *.txt|Find/V "---------- ">"Combined.log"&&Ren "Combined.log" "Combined.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks again @Compo!

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem with this code:

```
Find /v "" *.txt> "Combined.txt"

Type Combined.txt | findstr /v TXT > Output.txt

del Combined.txt

ren Output.txt Combined.txt
```

First line combine all text files.

Second line Search and Delete lines containg the string "**TXT**" and create new **Output.txt** file.

Third line delete the **Combined.txt** file.

Fourth Rename **Output.txt** to **Combined.txt**

The result looks like this:

```
abc

blue

123

abc

yellow

123

abc
```

It's all :)

Comment: `findstr /v TXT > Output.txt` won't work. `find` needs a quoted string

Comment: ok I didn't know that `findstr` can work with non-quoted strings. `find` requires you to quote or it'll return an error

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc : Not the case. Omitting the quotes in a `findstr` works - but I don't recommend it. Your comment is confused - are you referring to `find` or `findstr` ?

Comment: Why not just use the TYPE or COPY commands directly with a wildcard?  `TYPE *.txt>combined.log` or `copy *.txt combined.log` then do a rename: `rename combined.log combined.txt`

Comment: @Magoo my comment is very clear, `findstr` can work without quote, `find` needs a quoted string

Comment: @Squashman, when they were offered the option of using `Type` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46444879/6738015) yesterday, they didn't like the fact it put additional whitespace in their output, providing [this in explanation](https://m.imgur.com/gallery/Lx8umkH).

Answer (score 0):

```
del combined.txt
copy *.txt >combined.tmp
ren combined.tmp combined.txt
```

Remove the first line to include the current "combined.txt" into the final version.

Comment: This .bat generated the file with the following text inside: The file can not be copied onto itself. 0 file (s).

Comment: I can see no way in which that could possibly happen with the code I posted.

Comment: Hum... Quotes, maybe?

Comment: The error message indicates that the destination file, `combined.tmp` is included in the fileset to be copied, which is `*.txt` and that *excludes* `combined.tmp`.

Comment: I understood, but anyway my problem has already been solved. thank you for the explanation.